# Parity dev chain automine

Tags: private-blockchain, parity

How can I enable automine feature of parity? Do I NEED to attach an extra miner?

I want to deploy/test my contracts with truffle (ganache is creating problems :/)

Answer (score 1):

Running parity with `--chain dev` or `--config dev` flag (they are equivalent) you will run parity with an InstantSeal consensus that will basically validate blocks every 2min.

You do not need to attach a miner. In Parity 1.9, an account is automatically attached with a very big amount of Eth attached. There is no password to sign transaction (empty string).

Beware that any transaction that would reach the gas limit (Currently 4,700,000 Wei) would not be integrated in a block.

More info to customize the Private Development Chain on [Parity wiki](https://wiki.parity.io/Private-development-chain)

Comment: I have created POA (Aura) privatenet.In this case how can I get ether.